# Forcing to save xlsx format in client side from xlsm file in server side

Tags: vba, excel

I have myfile.xlsm formate file in server side as read only in that i wrote some VBA to file columns in excel.When client access that file i'm just showing the filled file.While client tend to save the file it goes to SaveAs because it read only.It saving as myfile.xlsm in client side.Now my problem is  :)

if client tend to save the file from saveas option it is suppose to save only as myfile.xlsx formate as ordinary xml file not macro enabled file.

What i have to do in VBA to do this action (may be write some thing in before save event)..??

Comment: Check out this code, you might be able to adapt it. http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/prevent-save-name.htm

Answer (score 0):

I have created the one private method and add this line 
 `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="Formula.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook` 
and calling this method .. ha it worked !!